# MySQL FOREIGN KEY assistance

Tags: mysql, database, syntax, foreign-keys

I'm working on a database assignment and have run into this error.

The database should look like...

```
Legend: **Primary Key** *Foreign Key
```

.

```
Movies (**title, year**, length, genre, *studioName, *producerID) 
StarsIn(***movieTitle, *movieYear, *starName**) 
MovieStar(**name**, birthdate, address, gender) 
MovieMaker(**ID**, name, address)
Studio (**name**, address, *presidentID)
```

And my code looks like this...

```
CREATE TABLE Movies (
title varchar(50),
year int,
length int,
genre varchar(50),
studioName varchar(50),
producerID varchar(50),
PRIMARY KEY (title,year)
FOREIGN KEY (studioName) REFERENCES Studio(name),
FOREIGN KEY (producerID) REFERENCES MovieMaker(ID),
);

CREATE TABLE StarsIn (
movieTitle varchar(50),
movieYear int,
starName varchar(50),
PRIMARY KEY (movieTitle,movieYear,starName),
FOREIGN KEY (movieTitle) REFERENCES Movies(title),
FOREIGN KEY (movieYear) REFERENCES Movies(year),
FOREIGN KEY (starName) REFERENCES MovieStar(name)
);

CREATE TABLE MovieStar (
name varchar(50),
birthdate int,
address varchar(50),
gender varchar(50),
PRIMARY KEY (name)
);

CREATE TABLE MovieMaker (
ID varchar(50),
name varchar(50),
address varchar(50),
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Studio (
name varchar(50),
address varchar(50),
presidentID varchar(50),
PRIMARY KEY (name),
FOREIGN KEY (presidentID) REFERENCES MovieMaker(ID)
);
```

However, I get quite a few errors stating that the syntax for my foreign keys are off. Any chance someone could lend a helping hand?

Comment: And the error messages are... ?

Answer (score 1):

Tables referencing other tables via foreign keys may only be defined *after* the referenced tables already exist. You must therefore reorder your tables so that those which are referenced in `FOREIGN KEY` constraints get created first.

Additionally, the foreign keys referencing `Movies.year` and `Movies.title` are going to fail because you do not have indices defined on those columns *individually*. You do have them as a composite `PRIMARY KEY`, but they need their own indices.

```
/* MovieStar, MovieMaker are referenced by other tables
   but have no FKs of their own, so create them first */
CREATE TABLE MovieStar (
  name varchar(50),
  birthdate int,
  address varchar(50),
  gender varchar(50),
  PRIMARY KEY (name)
);

CREATE TABLE MovieMaker (
  ID varchar(50),
  name varchar(50),
  address varchar(50),
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

/* Studio can be created next, referencing only MovieMaker */
CREATE TABLE Studio (
  name varchar(50),
  address varchar(50),
  presidentID varchar(50),
  PRIMARY KEY (name),
  FOREIGN KEY (presidentID) REFERENCES MovieMaker(ID)
);

/* Movies references 2 of the above */
CREATE TABLE Movies (
  title varchar(50),
  year int,
  length int,
  genre varchar(50),
  studioName varchar(50),
  producerID varchar(50),
  /* A comma was missing here... */
  PRIMARY KEY (title,year),
  FOREIGN KEY (studioName) REFERENCES Studio(name),
  FOREIGN KEY (producerID) REFERENCES MovieMaker(ID),
  /* Add individual indices on Movies. Omitting this would result in errno 150 */
  INDEX (year),
  INDEX (title)
);

CREATE TABLE StarsIn (
  movieTitle varchar(50),
  movieYear int,
  starName varchar(50),
  PRIMARY KEY (movieTitle,movieYear,starName),
  FOREIGN KEY (movieTitle) REFERENCES Movies(title),
  FOREIGN KEY (movieYear) REFERENCES Movies(year),
  FOREIGN KEY (starName) REFERENCES MovieStar(name)
);
```

**Here is a demo** of the whole thing building properly: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eaf70c

Comment: You could just declare `FOREIGN KEY (movieTitle,movieYear) REFERENCES Movies (title,year)` which is probably more appropriate for this case.

Comment: @MichealBerkowski This works splendidly! I never knew order was that big of a deal in MySQL. Thanks a lot!